# Creating clickable SVG (map) and show information about country

Tags: android, svg

I am trying to make a world map made using SVG data (looks like the easiest way to do it?) clickable on Android. However, I am struggling to find the best approach to do is. One possible way seems to be using HTML and JavaScript in the app or using some type of third party library. But I have not found any library that makes this possible so far?

The goal is to show information about a country when a user clicks on it, based on the SVG data.

Comment: using `d3` would be one of the easiest approaches. check their [world map example](http://bl.ocks.org/micahstubbs/8e15870eb432a21f0bc4d3d527b2d14f).

Comment: i think you can use this one :) https://github.com/MohammadRezaei92/IranMapSvg

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use a third package only to do that (unless this library supports tree shaking).
Doing it manually in HTML/CSS/JS might be a bit cumbersome and slow to develop, but I think the end result is going to be leaner. We can also achieve a lot of cool animations that might deliver a really unique and engaging UX.

I have created a simple SVG of Italy and divided it into north, sud, and center.
Every "region" is a  tag, hence I can add logic/styles on click/hover on each of these tags of the SVG.

In my simple example, I highlight the "regions" on mouse hover,
and on click, I render a simple modal (that auto-closes after 1.5seconds) and shows a description of the region.

```js
function showInfo(str) {
  const divElement = document.querySelector('div')
  divElement.innerText = getDescription(str);
  divElement.classList.add('show-desc');
  setTimeout(function(){ divElement.classList.remove('show-desc'); }, 1500);
}

function getDescription(str) {
 if (str === 'nord') {
    return 'Northen Italy is famous for Polenta';
  } else if (str === 'center') {
    return 'Center Italy is famous for Rome, Caput Mundi';
  } else {
    return 'Southern Italy is famous for the good food and beatiful sea';
  }
}
```

```css
svg g:hover {
  fill: red;
}

.show-desc {
  position: fixed;
  top: 125px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  height: 125px;
  background: gray;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 1920 1080" style="enable-background:new 0 0 1920 1080;" xml:space="preserve">
<g class="center" onclick="showInfo('center')">
    <path d="M1040.3,508.35c-6.59-6-13.2-11.98-19.54-18.24c-6.85-6.78-11.45-14.99-14.28-24.21c-0.58-1.89-0.72-4.77-4.11-3.05
        c1.91-1.6,2.63-3.33,1.65-5.95c-4.04-10.87-7.84-21.84-11.81-32.74c-0.92-2.54-2.22-4.94-3.21-7.45c-1.57-4.02-5.79-1.97-8.21-3.65
        c-5.64-3.92-11.01-8.24-16.49-12.4c-1.92,0.79-3.85,1.56-5.78,2.31c-10.63,4.12-21.79,7.11-32.52,11.05
        c-2.58,0.95-5.14,1.95-7.66,3.04c-0.5,0.22-1.01,0.43-1.5,0.65c-11.94,5.35-23.59,11.36-35.38,17.04
        c-15.02,7.24-30.95,14.99-47.46,19.59c-0.28,0.55-0.58,1.11-0.92,1.67c-0.47,0.79,0.21,2.28,0.38,3.63
        c9.54-3.99,14.13-0.25,13.07,8.81c3.99,2.69,7.97,4.75,11.13,7.69c2.79,2.6,4.43,6.39,7.01,9.27c4.39,4.92,4.07,7.06-3.54,11.17
        c1.41,1.08,2.83,2.15,4.24,3.23c0.29-0.76,0.59-1.52,0.88-2.28c2.53-0.2,5.07-0.33,7.58-0.61c2.2-0.25,4.39-0.68,6.58-1.03
        c0.77,1.31,1.22,3.21,2.37,3.85c6.35,3.54,11.24,8.07,13.09,15.46c0.55,2.18,2.04,4.16,3.28,6.12c0.46,0.72,1.41,1.43,2.22,1.56
        c8.48,1.36,16.78,9.26,18.48,17.4c0.28,1.35,1.52,2.64,2.59,3.67c4.98,4.78,11.1,8.78,14.79,14.39c3.29,4.99,8.31,4.92,12.33,7.44
        c2.82,1.77,6.36,2.62,8.72,4.8c0.58,0.54,1.09,1.15,1.56,1.81c9.25-0.76,18.05-3.88,26.25-8.53c8.73-4.96,16.68-11.17,24.06-18.06
        c-2.17-1.29-4.32-2.62-6.54-3.83c2.22,1.21,4.37,2.54,6.54,3.83c4.03-3.75,7.89-7.7,11.61-11.78c0.42-0.75,1.01-1.36,1.66-1.83
        c5.26-5.86,10.27-11.92,15.11-17.92c1.26-1.56,2.49-3.13,3.72-4.71C1041.55,509.22,1040.86,508.85,1040.3,508.35z M969.99,474.01
        c0.76-0.39,1.47-0.62,2.13-0.7C971.46,473.38,970.75,473.61,969.99,474.01c-0.57,2.85-1.92,4.66-3.95,5.71
        C968.08,478.67,969.42,476.86,969.99,474.01z M976.75,476.85c-0.01,0.07-0.01,0.14,0.01,0.2
        C976.74,477,976.74,476.93,976.75,476.85z M964.53,480.31c0.5-0.15,0.97-0.33,1.41-0.55C965.5,479.98,965.03,480.16,964.53,480.31z
         M977.03,476.11c-0.06,0.2-0.19,0.43-0.25,0.63C976.84,476.54,976.97,476.32,977.03,476.11c-0.87-1.29-1.86-2.2-3-2.6
        C975.17,473.92,976.16,474.83,977.03,476.11z M973.98,473.49c-0.01,0-0.03-0.01-0.04-0.01
        C973.96,473.48,973.97,473.48,973.98,473.49z M972.61,473.27c-0.07,0-0.14,0.01-0.2,0.01
        C972.48,473.28,972.54,473.27,972.61,473.27z"/>
    <path d="M924.11,404.04c0.21-0.08,0.42-0.15,0.62-0.23c-1.37-0.28-2.73-0.56-4.12-0.73c-1.46-0.18-3.2,0.34-4.32-0.3
        c-0.62-0.35-0.21-2.48-0.27-3.81c-0.98,1.21-1.96,2.43-3.1,3.85c-1.96-0.32-4.05-0.65-6.14-0.99c1.86,0.64,3.69,1.68,5.59,1.83
        C916.27,403.97,920.19,403.98,924.11,404.04z"/>
</g>
<g class="nord" onclick="showInfo('nord')">
    <path d="M925.12,324.15L925.12,324.15C925.14,324.22,925.14,324.24,925.12,324.15z"/>
    <path d="M988.18,259.23c-3.55-1.81-3.88-3.38-2.74-6.48c0.75-2.04,1.29-4.15,1.75-5.64c-2.82-0.76-4.73-1.28-6.65-1.8
        c1.08-2.01,1.99-4.14,3.3-5.99c1.37-1.94,3.12-3.6,5.26-6.02c-4.74-1.47-8.44-2.63-12.72-3.96c-1.78-4.75,2.71-12.51,10.14-14.34
        c3.66-0.9,3.42-2.65,3.55-5.73c-15.19-2.23-30.23-4.44-44.53-6.55c-1.05,2.27-2.18,4.67-3.3,7.08c0.12-2.75,1.16-7.45,0.2-7.91
        c-3.33-1.58-9.24-3.52-10.75-1.97c-3.43,3.5-7.06,2.63-10.71,3.25c3.09-1.04,6.19-2.09,9.26-3.12c-2.21-5.12-7.35-7.37-6.86-12.83
        c0.05-0.6-0.9-1.82-1.43-1.85c-5.54-0.33-4.9-4.79-5.78-7.75c1.72-2,3.16-3.66,5.55-6.44c-2.66,0.16-3.68,0-4.53,0.31
        c-4.51,1.63-8.96,3.41-13.46,5.06c-2,0.73-4.67,2.4-6,1.7c-7.44-3.94-14.67,0.37-21.97,0.06c-4.43-0.19-7.28,2.83-8.81,7.32
        c-0.8,2.35-2.95,5.74-4.79,5.94c-3.74,0.4-8.63,1.8-10.8-3.96c-0.48-1.28-3.52-2.06-5.46-2.22c-2.38-0.2-4.84,0.48-7.8,0.85
        c-0.38,1.56-0.59,3.73-1.42,5.61c-1.58,3.6-4.33,7.13,1.36,9.71c0.38,0.17,0.6,1.75,0.27,2.3c-2.65,4.33-0.15,6.18,3.46,7.57
        c-1.8-0.7-3.67-1.24-5.36-2.14c-1.53-0.81-2.86-2.01-4.28-3.04c-1.4-1.02-3.51-1.76-4.07-3.13c-1.69-4.12-5.31-2.55-6.34-1.16
        c-2.01,2.71-3.14,6.33-3.67,9.73c-0.18,1.13,2.58,2.72,4.46,4.55c-2.76,2.22-3.01,5.14,0.04,8.22c0.31,0.31-0.62,2.73-1.41,3.04
        c-0.95,0.36-2.95-0.12-3.46-0.91c-1.36-2.09-2.09-4.59-3.23-6.84c-0.4-0.78-1.36-1.97-1.89-1.88c-3.55,0.57-7.7,0.51-10.42,2.42
        c-3.93,2.76-8.11,3-10.15-1.45c-1.44-3.14-2.09-6.65-3.11-10.06c-0.46,0.02-1.48,0.18-2.47,0.11c-1.52-0.12-3.84-1.07-4.35-0.46
        c-0.94,1.13-1.37,3.29-1.01,4.78c1.2,4.93-0.03,9.13-2.96,13.01c-2.61,3.45-4.89,7.23-7.97,10.2c-4.37,4.21-3.99,7.93,0.06,11.72
        c-1.12,1.82-2.05,3.35-3.24,5.28c-1.47-0.96-3.28-1.5-3.93-2.68c-1.94-3.53-3.42-7.31-5.25-11.38c0.27-0.8,1.48-2.63,1.2-4.19
        c-0.17-0.94-2.66-1.46-4.11-2.17c-0.73,1.63-1.4,3.31-2.23,4.89c-0.36,0.68-1.07,1.17-1.61,1.75c1.27-3.98-1.6-11.29-6.46-14.31
        c-3.72-2.3-3.67-4.76-2.6-8.36c0.79-2.65,0.58-5.59,0.81-8.4c-0.59-0.34-1.18-0.67-1.77-1.01c-5.22,4.39-10.43,8.79-15.72,13.24
        c0.56,1.79,2.49,4.75,1.7,5.95c-2.75,4.23-5.76,9.11-9.95,11.35c-3.75,2.01-4.79,3.77-4.39,7.37c-6.7-3.98-12.85-11-21.56-3.89
        c-6.08-0.96-12.62,5.86-17.46-0.62c-2.96,1.43-5.42,2.49-7.75,3.78c-1.69,0.94-4.45,2.06-4.56,3.3c-0.21,2.34,0.91,4.92,1.94,7.19
        c0.47,1.04,2.28,1.39,3.04,2.39c0.88,1.15,1.73,2.65,1.8,4.04c0.22,4.26,1.06,7.9,5.86,9.13c0.82,1.8,1.65,3.61,2.54,5.55
        c-0.86,1.89-2.26,4-2.74,6.3c-0.59,2.81-12.28,10.69-14.97,9.43c-3.85-1.79-6.87-0.37-10.94,2.27c1.87,2.16,3.5,3.94,5.01,5.82
        c0.48,0.59,0.97,1.46,0.9,2.15c-0.67,6.81,2.79,9.47,9.16,9.85c1.15,0.07,2.79,1.83,3.15,3.1c0.76,2.72,0.83,5.63,1.22,8.74
        c-3.13-0.6-5.33,0.36-5.55,4.14c-0.05,0.88-0.77,1.93-1.49,2.53c-2.48,2.06-4.91,3.55-2.58,7.72c1.26,2.26-0.34,5.98,0.6,8.6
        c1.46,4.09,3.59,8,8.62,9.24c1.94,0.48,3.61,2.12,5.35,3.32c4.59,3.17,9.24,5.7,15.11,3.37c2.04-0.81,4.28-1.11,6.43-1.65
        c-0.31,0.47-0.63,0.94-0.94,1.41c1.86,1.7,3.72,3.39,5.58,5.09c-4.42,4.48-9.05,8.79-13.18,13.53c-2.03,2.33,0.29,7.06,3.3,6.68
        c6.92-0.88,13.86-2.08,20.6-3.86c6.94-1.84,9.77-8,12.74-13.84c0.85-1.67,2.16-3.96,3.63-4.29c4.6-1.04,6.18-4.31,7.71-8.07
        c1.2-2.96,14.36-10.83,17.06-9.68c6.59,2.8,14.97,1.8,19.54,9.42c2.78-4.17,5.13-1.55,7.26,0.12c6.78,5.33,13.41,10.85,20.14,16.24
        c1.01,0.8,2.25,1.3,3.47,1.99c0.23-1.07,0.44-2.01,0.44-2.02c3.12,0.74,5.87,1.39,8.62,2.04c-0.1-1.58-0.2-3.17-0.3-4.75
        c0.99,0.45,1.98,0.9,3.02,1.38c-0.62,1.68-1.12,3.02-1.56,4.2c0.3,0.39,0.38,0.55,0.51,0.65c7.2,6.03,10.94,13.47,10.55,23.12
        c-0.28,7.08,0.74,13.64,5.17,20.14c3.63,5.31,6.73,11.06,7.23,17.19c3.48-1.14,6.92-2.38,10.31-3.68
        c24.02-9.21,46.3-22.25,69.94-32.32c2.48-1.05,5-2.01,7.53-2.94c-3.92-0.06-7.84-0.07-11.73-0.38c-1.9-0.15-3.73-1.19-5.59-1.83
        c2.09,0.34,4.19,0.68,6.14,0.99c1.15-1.42,2.13-2.64,3.1-3.85c2.18-2.31,2.16-6.74,6.6-6.89c3.79-1.5,7.59-2.99,11.01-4.34
        c1.4,2.25,2.36,3.79,3.31,5.32c1.12,1.18,2.07,2.66,3.42,3.46c1.12,0.66,2.71,0.5,4.09,0.71c2.23-3.85,3.01-6.57-1.54-10.33
        c-7.19-5.95-14.54-12.48-16.36-22.53c-1-5.49-1.61-11.05-2.12-16.61c-0.45-4.83-0.71-9.71-0.6-14.55c0.03-1.18,1.82-2.33,3.28-4.05
        c-0.04-0.18-0.18-0.72-0.32-1.28c0.77,1.7,1.55,3.4,2.32,5.1c0.31,0.16,0.62,0.31,0.93,0.47c0.19-2.35,0.38-4.71,0.57-7.06
        c0.3,0.01,0.6,0.02,0.89,0.02c0.22,1.43,0.44,2.85,0.66,4.28c1.56-1.45,1.99-3.13,2.7-4.67c1.27-2.76,2.02-4.36-1.74-6.68
        c-3.39-2.09-8.63-4.84-6.72-11.08c0.25-0.8-1.04-2.96-1.33-2.91c-5.13,0.9-3.18-3.05-3.5-5.05c-1.05,0.05-1.88,0.08-2.71,0.12
        c0.23-0.77,0.32-1.63,0.73-2.29c0.94-1.52,3.07-3.07,2.91-4.39c-1.1-9.07,8.92-7.42,11.83-12.53c0.04-0.08,1.79,0.82,3.35,1.54
        c-2.73,1.99-4.91,3.58-7.09,5.17c0.33,0.5,0.66,1,0.99,1.51c4.95-2.48,9.9-4.96,14.85-7.45c5.02-2.53,10.03-5.09,15.17-7.7
        c-0.09-0.25-0.45-1.3-0.82-2.36c1.05,0.64,2.11,1.29,4.29,2.62c-3.02-4.9-2.34-7.1,2.17-7.67c2.81-0.35,5.93,1.01,8.76,2.03
        c1.37,0.5,2.39,1.99,4.35,3.73c1.52-1.98,3.42-4.46,5.65-7.38c5.43,1.29,7.87,6.37,10.55,11.17c0.02,0.04-1.2,0.78-1.84,1.19
        c0.08,0.35,0.17,0.69,0.25,1.04c2.64-0.68,5.27-1.36,7.91-2.03c0.19-0.79,0.38-1.58,0.57-2.36
        C997.07,265.83,993.04,261.71,988.18,259.23z M916.69,200.31c-0.83,0.27-1.81,0.5-2.53,0.8
        C914.88,200.81,915.85,200.58,916.69,200.31z M853.85,253.49C853.85,253.49,853.85,253.49,853.85,253.49
        c-2.06,0.16-4.14,0.21-6.18,0.43C849.72,253.7,851.8,253.65,853.85,253.49z M795.23,352.43c-0.19,0.14-0.37,0.29-0.55,0.43
        C794.86,352.72,795.04,352.57,795.23,352.43z M767.67,320.75c-0.59-0.13-1.23-0.21-1.9-0.27v0
        C766.43,320.54,767.08,320.62,767.67,320.75z M764.75,318.54c-1.07-2.06-2.14-4.11-3.22-6.16
        C762.62,314.43,763.68,316.49,764.75,318.54z M747.33,258.94c0.31,0.38,0.64,0.76,0.94,1.14c0.39,1.28,0.65,2.68,0.94,4.05
        c-0.29-1.37-0.55-2.77-0.94-4.05C747.97,259.7,747.65,259.33,747.33,258.94c-0.31-0.38-0.61-0.77-0.87-1.19
        C746.72,258.17,747.02,258.56,747.33,258.94z M793.79,353.56C793.79,353.56,793.79,353.56,793.79,353.56
        c1.43,1.54,2.83,3.1,4.28,4.61C796.62,356.66,795.21,355.1,793.79,353.56z M861.33,374.94c-3.2,0.18-3.65-1.4-2.73-3.98
        c2.04,3.46,2.67,3.63,11.42,2.84c-0.72-1.49-1.36-2.83-1.75-3.62c2.6-1.26,5.11-2.48,7.61-3.69c-1.5,1.5-2.99,3-5.01,5.03
        c1.58,2.69-0.03,3.97-4.1,3.53C864.97,374.83,863.14,374.84,861.33,374.94z M916.76,200.29c0.21-0.07,0.41-0.14,0.6-0.22l0,0
        C917.17,200.15,916.97,200.22,916.76,200.29z"/>
</g>
<g class="sud" onclick="showInfo('sud')">
    <path d="M1103.82,787.01c-3.06,2.33-7.32,3.08-12.58,5.12c-2.78,4.15-4.34,4.65-10.82,3.13c-3.09-0.73-5.73-2.77-9.64-1.03
        c-3.49,1.56-7.54,1.58-9.56,5.66c-0.38,0.76-1.51,1.38-2.41,1.63c-7.95,2.13-15.69,5.17-24.26,4.13
        c-6.29-0.77-12.39-1.12-18.56,2.49c-6.13,3.59-15.31-1.17-18.09-8.34c-4.06,1.72-8.03,3.11-8.75-3.7
        c-0.12-1.12-2.91-3.06-3.93-2.77c-3.35,0.95-6.2,3.65-10.2,2.05c-0.37-0.15-2.56,2.17-2.44,3.17c0.76,6.23-4.7,6.74-7.96,7.29
        c-1.96,0.33-4.82-3.53-6.95-5.81c-1.19-1.27-1.72-3.15-2.13-3.93c-2.83,2.69-4.89,6.25-7.62,6.89c-5.21,1.2-6.33,4.67-7.36,8.75
        c-0.96,3.82-3.08,7.88-2.44,11.43c0.64,3.59,0.96,9.02,7.05,9.46c0.93,0.07,2.06,1.73,2.52,2.88c1.44,3.63,3.79,3.79,7.21,2.95
        c5.59-1.37,11.29-2.2,15.03,4.04c0.37,0.61,1.74,0.98,2.58,0.89c5.32-0.56,8.38,2.61,11.78,6.05c3.19,3.22,7.05,6.67,11.22,7.78
        c4.68,1.26,7.63,4.17,11.34,6.51c4.71,2.98,10.32,6.69,15.4,6.5c14.2-0.53,23.53,4.09,29.33,17.05c0.73,1.63,1.46,3.91,2.8,4.5
        c4.77,2.08,9.79,3.61,14.76,5.22c0.85,0.27,2.04,0.23,2.82-0.17c5.11-2.63,9.23,1.6,13.91,1.88c1.25,0.07,2.47,0.48,3.71,0.74
        c0.14-1.35,0.39-2.71,0.39-4.06c0-3.19-1.25-7,0.07-9.45c2.49-4.64,6.43-8.5,10.01-12.98c-0.57-1.14-1.08-3.89-2.7-5.01
        c-5.26-3.65-5.9-6.51-1.27-10.68c-1.01-0.63-1.88-1.44-2.91-1.79c-6.19-2.1-9.07-9.83-5.92-15.37c1.75-3.07,4.14-6.44,4.16-9.69
        c0.07-7.22,4.26-12.28,7.44-17.96c3.87-6.92,7.72-13.86,11.56-20.8c1.11-2,2.19-4.02,3.29-6.03
        C1110.32,783.41,1107.38,784.29,1103.82,787.01z"/>
    <path d="M794.02,612.52c-0.55-1.73-0.38-3.69-0.65-6.86c-1.48-1.14-4.2-3.25-6.53-5.05c0.93-1.58,2.12-3.61,3.23-5.5
        c-1.46-0.73-2.94-1.47-3.51-1.75c0-3.01,0.28-5.1-0.22-6.97c-0.11-0.41-3.03-0.06-3.31-0.06c-2.81-1.96-4.98-3.46-7.13-4.98
        c-0.97-0.68-1.89-1.45-2.9-2.06c-1.13-0.69-2.46-1.89-3.47-1.69c-0.99,0.2-1.71,1.86-2.5,2.92c-1.18,1.6-2.28,4.59-3.48,4.62
        c-6.62,0.17-8.84,5.81-12.52,9.45c-2.52,2.49-4.34,5.34-8.55,4.88c-1.28-0.14-2.97,0.73-4.02,1.64c-8.16,7.08-18.38,4.15-21.4-6.21
        c-0.05-0.16-0.57-0.18-1.83-0.53c0.44,2.38,1.8,5.35,1,6.14c-5.66,5.64-1.04,13.34-4.41,19.02c2.62,0.5,5.06,0.96,8.12,1.54
        c1.44,4.98,3.03,10.46,4.95,17.08c2.96,0.86,3.55,3.87,2.04,8.09c-0.63,1.77-0.64,4.08-0.08,5.88c1.38,4.43-0.28,6.51-4.25,6.81
        c-0.22,2.8-0.67,5.23-0.48,7.62c0.09,1.11,1.46,3.06,2.2,3.04c5.75-0.2,6.61,0.78,5.02,6.36c-0.65,2.3-1.19,4.62-1.76,6.85
        c-0.77-0.97-1.92-2.41-3.61-4.52c-0.14,1.86-0.27,2.79-0.28,3.73c-0.08,5.54,1.26,11.14-3.4,16.03c-1.53,1.61-1.85,5.96-0.78,8.1
        c1.93,3.89,1.82,6.49-1.82,8.75c1.96,4.13,3.84,8.07,5.71,12c0.14-0.25,0.25-0.51,0.43-0.72c0.05-0.06,0.39-0.03,0.43,0.05
        c2.25,4.35,4.48,8.7,6.85,13.33c2.74-2.28,5.81-2.78,9.19,0.1c0.87,0.74,3.33,0.31,4.66-0.36c1.88-0.95,3.68-2.41,4.97-4.07
        c1.44-1.86,3.73-4.82,3.13-6.19c-2.21-5.01,0.18-7.9,3.5-10.96c1.03,0.75,2.07,1.52,3.34,2.45c3.06-4.11,6.41-2.25,9.58-0.25
        c1.36,0.86,2.16,2.65,3.55,3.38c2.17,1.13,4.59,2.04,6.98,2.32c0.75,0.09,2.28-1.99,2.6-3.29c1.16-4.72,1.99-9.53,2.89-14.32
        c1.12-6.01,2.25-12.01,3.26-18.04c1.6-9.59,3.15-19.2,4.6-28.81c0.15-0.98-0.26-2.25-0.83-3.1c-5.75-8.59-5.05-11.77,2.48-19.25
        c2.47-2.45,4.83-6.82,4.44-9.96C798.71,623.51,795.8,618.11,794.02,612.52z"/>
    <path d="M1261.11,645.24c-4.38-10-11.32-17.69-21.18-22.7c-2.14-1.08-5.17-2.87-5.43-4.67c-0.6-4.15-3.48-5.59-6.31-6.8
        c-6.06-2.59-12.42-4.47-18.55-6.89c-3.19-1.26-6.69-2.49-9.14-4.73c-8.91-8.17-18.97-13.77-30.84-16.34
        c-5-1.08-9.92-2.75-14.67-4.66c-7.84-3.15-15.56-6.61-23.23-10.16c-3.88-1.8-8.02-3.53-11.17-6.28c-4.71-4.12-3.76-9.21,1.24-12.66
        c3.11-2.15,6.17-4.54,8.68-7.33c1.17-1.3,1.67-3.99,1.27-5.78c-1.23-5.41-5.07-7.52-10.9-6.61c-4.75,0.74-9.48,1.83-14.26,2.19
        c-9.17,0.7-18.37,1-27.33,1.45c-0.56,1.45-1.12,2.89-1.68,4.33c0.55-2.78,0.42-4.93-2.81-6.38c-5.27-2.36-10.28-5.28-14.9-7.7
        c-2.87,3.56-5.29,6.58-7.72,9.59c-1.45,2.32-3.04,4.57-4.32,6.98c-2.6,4.88-2.47,4.62-6.09,0.38c-0.22-0.26-0.46-0.52-0.72-0.78
        c-6.45,7.32-13.22,14.32-20.51,20.8v0c-0.02,0.02-0.04,0.03-0.05,0.05c-9.11,8.09-19.38,15.55-30.58,20.48
        c1.86,0.89,3.5,1.86,4.76,2.38c3.54-0.97,5.66-1.77,7.84-2.08c1.78-0.25,3.64,0.07,5.46,0.14l0,0c0.3,1.06,0.38,2.26,0.94,3.17
        c5.43,8.89,12.87,16.72,14.46,27.61c1.05-0.66,2.46-2.11,3.09-1.83c2.68,1.19,4.81,1.16,7.21-0.76c0.6-0.48,2.68,0.49,3.84,1.19
        c1.4,0.85,2.41,2.36,3.81,3.18c5.14,3.02,5.16,2.94,0.93,7.33c-1.58,1.64-3.05,3.38-4.57,5.07c3.4-0.52,5.97-1.63,8.63-2.43
        c3.99-1.2,8.03-2.3,12.1-3.2c1.35-0.29,3.67-0.35,4.17,0.41c3.84,5.73,7.4,11.66,10.89,17.62c0.37,0.63-0.07,1.91-0.45,2.75
        c-1.14,2.55-2.44,5.04-3.58,7.37c2.92,2.05,5.24,5.05,7.69,5.15c6.23,0.26,9.21,4.39,12.52,8.38c2.63,3.18,7.14,4.21,9.07,1.37
        c3.1-4.56,6.89-4.4,11.28-2.85c1.3,2.56,0.96,6.89,5.93,5.44c0.29,3.25,0.1,6.64,0.98,9.73c1.89,6.65,2.78,14.42,6.9,19.4
        c5.87,7.09,8.57,14.55,10.28,23.18c1.2,6.05,2.57,13.29,6.58,17.22c4.66,4.57,3.6,8.37,2.44,12.77c-0.79,2.99-2.94,4.82-6.8,4.21
        c-5.75-0.9-8.95,3.47-12.48,6.19c1.98,2.92,5.09,5.46,4.76,7.42c-0.94,5.64-2.9,11.23-5.28,16.46c-0.8,1.77-4.21,2.22-6.11,3.69
        c-1.33,1.03-3,2.74-3.01,4.16c-0.02,3.6,1.04,7.18,1.23,10.8c0.28,5.41,3.4,8.34,9.08,7.96c2.48-0.17,4.96-0.7,7.42-0.62
        c6.96,0.23,9.92-2.33,10.8-9.29c1.17-9.16,6.27-15.81,14.16-20.15c6.6-3.63,9.01-7.49,7.87-14.94c-0.5-3.28-1.97-6.57-1.74-9.76
        c0.25-3.52,0.98-7.91,3.25-10.17c3.53-3.51,8.36-5.92,12.98-8.04c2.2-1.01,5.22-0.08,7.83-0.39c2.47-0.29,5.49,1.53,7.29-1.92
        c1.54-2.97,2.28-5.35-0.6-8.25c-1.31-1.32-1.16-4.24-1.38-6.46c-0.13-1.28,0.59-2.64,0.45-3.92c-0.48-4.4-1.17-8.77-1.93-14.26
        c-4.29-2.49-10.51-5.09-15.4-9.26c-3.39-2.89-6.3-4.07-10.52-3.91c-3.23,0.12-5.77-0.73-7.72-4.64
        c-3.24-6.52-0.87-10.95,2.83-15.77c0.88-1.15,1.36-2.94,1.29-4.4c-0.15-2.89-0.81-5.76-1.31-8.95c-2.64-0.21-5.73-0.45-8.77-0.68
        c-0.63,1.76-1.12,3.16-1.62,4.55c-0.69-5.11,1.39-6.21,6.3-5.25c7.06,1.38,8.88-0.12,11.28-7.1c0.86-2.51,2.14-4.89,2.82-7.43
        c0.54-2.02,0.46-4.21,0.65-6.32c1.25-0.16,2.82,0.1,3.69-0.56c2.47-1.88,4.38-5.44,7-5.97c4.82-0.98,9.99-0.28,14.99-0.28
        c-2.34,2.56-3.94,4.3-5.89,6.43c8.86,3.48,16.33,8.12,25.6,5.86c2.61-0.64,5.61,0.18,8.42,0.49c1.66,0.19,10.8,11.31,10.67,12.92
        c-0.05,0.61-0.97,1.34-0.81,1.74c1.3,3.22,1.91,7.55,4.34,9.29c5.03,3.6,11.05,5.81,17.24,8.88c0.49-2.42,0.87-3.36,0.82-4.27
        c-0.31-5.72,0.12-11.15,3.72-16.06C1261.52,649.45,1261.78,646.76,1261.11,645.24z M1077.8,550.08c0.27-0.28,0.51-0.58,0.7-0.91
        C1078.31,549.5,1078.07,549.8,1077.8,550.08s-0.58,0.54-0.91,0.77C1077.22,550.62,1077.53,550.36,1077.8,550.08z M1028.4,562.81
        c-0.57,0.02-1.06,0.06-1.47,0.14C1027.35,562.87,1027.83,562.83,1028.4,562.81z M1036.42,563.52c-0.41,0.01-0.81,0.03-1.22,0.04
        c-0.81,0.03-1.63,0.07-2.44,0.08c0.81-0.01,1.63-0.04,2.44-0.08C1035.6,563.54,1036.01,563.53,1036.42,563.52
        c0.19,0.09,0.37,0.19,0.55,0.29C1036.79,563.71,1036.61,563.61,1036.42,563.52z M1041.54,565.84c0.57,0.3,1.13,0.61,1.69,0.94
        C1042.67,566.46,1042.1,566.14,1041.54,565.84z M1063.33,566.06c-1.93,0.43-3.82,0.9-5.39,2.06c-1.45,1.07-2.82,1.68-4.12,1.96
        c-0.65,0.14-1.29,0.19-1.91,0.18c0.62,0.01,1.26-0.04,1.91-0.18c1.3-0.28,2.67-0.89,4.12-1.96
        C1059.51,566.96,1061.41,566.48,1063.33,566.06c0.64-0.14,1.29-0.28,1.93-0.43C1064.62,565.78,1063.98,565.91,1063.33,566.06z
         M1071.84,561.49C1071.84,561.49,1071.84,561.49,1071.84,561.49c-0.41-0.65-0.76-1.24-1.05-1.78
        C1071.07,560.25,1071.42,560.84,1071.84,561.49c2.14,1.35,4.57,2.43,5.64,4.45C1076.41,563.92,1073.98,562.85,1071.84,561.49z
         M1094.23,588.22c-0.63-0.12-1.25-0.23-1.88-0.34C1092.98,587.99,1093.61,588.11,1094.23,588.22z"/>
    <path d="M715.41,724.42c1.01,3.2,2.01,6.4,3.38,10.73c2.03-3.64,3.31-5.93,4.59-8.22c-2.2-1.23-4.39-2.45-6.58-3.67
        C716.33,723.64,715.87,724.03,715.41,724.42z"/>
    <path d="M723.37,726.93c0.01,0.01,0.03,0.02,0.04,0.02c0,0,0,0-0.01-0.01c0.01,0,0.01,0.01,0.01,0.01
        c-0.01-0.02-0.02-0.04-0.03-0.06C723.39,726.9,723.38,726.91,723.37,726.93C723.37,726.93,723.37,726.93,723.37,726.93z"/>
</g>
</svg>

<div>Info Modal</div>
```